# Recreate Picture in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to recreate the image below in Latex. I have used the tikzpicture environment to plot the straight lines on an axis. However the curves are proving difficult. Does anyone have any ideas on what would be the best way to draw the curves.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Would be nice if you showed the code you already have, so people don't have to create the example from scratch.

Comment: If you're interested in TikZ-based version, it definitely worth a look to the `expanding waves` decoration.

Comment: It looks much easier to use vector graphics editor like Inkscape(http://www.inkscape.org/en/).

Answer (score 11):

A suggestion:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\rayangle{45}
\foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,3} {
  \draw  (\x,0) -- (\x,4);
  \draw  (3,2) ++(\rayangle:\x) arc[start angle=\rayangle,delta angle=-2*\rayangle,radius=\x];  
  }
\draw [gray,ultra thick,xshift=0.5\pgflinewidth] (3,0) -- (3,1.8) (3,2.2) -- (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: more compact perhaps ? `\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
  {%
   \draw (3,2) ++(30:\i*0.5) arc[start angle=30,delta angle=-2*30,radius=\i*0.5];
   \draw (\i*0.5,0) -- (\i*0.5,4);
   }`

Answer (score 10):

One approach could be to use the library `decorations.pathreplacing` from »[PGF/TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)« and draw a decorated path as `expanding waves` with specifications for `angle` and `segment length`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={
      expanding waves,
      angle=45,
      segment length=0.5cm
    }
  ]
    \foreach \x in {-3.5,-3  .0,...,-0.5}
      \draw (\x,-2) -- (\x,2);
    \draw [ultra thick] (0,-2) -- (0,-0.2) (0,0.2) -- (0,2);
    \draw[decorate] (0,0) -- (2.5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: beat me by few seconds. :)